# DialogFlow : 'facebook_welcome' event not triggered

Tags: nlp, chatbot, dialogflow-es, facebook-messenger

In my agent on DialogFlow, I created a new intent for [linear dialog](https://dialogflow.com/docs/dialogs#linear_dialog).

I want to get some user's data when the user clicks on the 'get started' button of facebook messenger.

I added the 'WELCOME' event in my intent. :

[image]

My issue is : When user clicks on 'get started', my intent is not triggered but my fallback intent does. (i.e event has not been triggered)

[image]

I tried to add that training phrase : 'facebook_welcome' (i think it's a bad idea because an event does not require any user input)

[image]

Then, the intent is triggered but the agent does not ask for dialog parameters, it says directly the intent's response like if the slot filling would be done.

What do I misunderstand ? Is there any versioning issue (V1 vs V2) ?

Thanks !

MC

Answer (score 1):

Add this new event and try to invoke the agent again. You need to scroll and search this event in the list.
[image]

Comment: I just did it and no effect. Thanks anyway

Comment: @mcanzerini Have you found any solution for this? I'm facing it right now.

Comment: No sorry. The project is no longer being developed.

Answer (score 0):

Think I solved this. What I did was adding `MessengerGetStarted` to Training phrases on my intent. Looks like this is the query-text that Facebook will send to DialogFlow. The `FACEBOOK_WELCOME` did not work for me either, but this little "workaround" actually did.

I also disabled ML up in the right corner (the three dots) on my intent, just to be sure.